# when a user login a jsp page change db table status

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp

i am new in jsp,ajax.. i want to a login page when the user login into the page the database table status will change no to yes.I tried  using ajax. but it getting an error. please help me anyone.

Answer (score -1):

So your trying to add a online status for mysql or using something else right? You will have to add another table, and add a function that will change the mysql to yes when the login and no to when the log out, I would help you with this but I have to go so i hope someone can help you with this. Its very simple! :)